# Как при перезагрузке использывать одну рандомную из трьох палитру цветов?

Tags: javascript, html

Сейчас у меня используеться одна палитра цветов а имеено массив firstColor. Но так же есть массивы secondColor и thirdColor. Я хочу что бы один массив при перезагрузке выбирался рандомно и использывалась только его вся палитра цветов.

```
<canvas class='canvas'><canvas>
```

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var angle = 360;
var speed = 1;
var rotation = 0;
window.onload = function(){

window.onresize = function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

};
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
function getDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2,) {
    var xDistance = x2-x1;
    var yDistance = y2-y1;
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDistance,2) + Math.pow(yDistance,2));
}
var firstColor =[
'#147CA6',
'#2CA4BF',
'#4ACAD9',
'#4AD9D9',
'#CEF2F2'
];
var secondColor = [
'#FFE2DF',
'#FFD6DC',
'#F5C1C7',
'#E8A0AB',
'#E8707B'
];
var thirdColor = [
  '#FFEE00',
  '#FFC200',
  '#FF9D00',
  '#FF7700',
  '#FF4800'
];
var colorArr =[ firstColor, secondColor, thirdColor];
function Circle(x,y,radius,color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 25;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
    this.color = firstColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstColor.length)];

    this.update = function(){
    this.draw();
    }
}
circleArr=[];
function init(){
    for(var i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        var x = randomInt(0 - canvas.width, canvas.width +canvas.width);
        var y = randomInt(0 - canvas.height, canvas.height + canvas.height);
        var radius = randomInt(1, 5);
        circleArr.push(new Circle(x,y,radius));
    }
}
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
     for(var i = 0; i < circleArr.length; i++){
        circleArr[i].update();
     }
     rotation += 0.00051;
}
init();
animate();

}
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ })` - кода загрузились все элементы старицы и [random](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Тут не так всё просто. Тут именно нужно сначала зарандомить 1 из 3 массивов а потом зарандомить цвета которые находяться только в этом массиве

Comment: @BlackCat Так если вы понимаете что нужно сделать, то в чем именно проблема?

Comment: В том что когда я пытаюсь сделать то что я хочу кодом. То выходит что сначала рандомиться одна из палитр как и задумано один рандомный цвет из этой палитры а после снова повторяеться цикл и уже берёться цвет из другого масива(палитры) и получаеться что кружочки закрашиваються рандомно с 3 палитр получаеться разноцветная каша.